# Setting brightness

Tags: brightness, settings, function-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [fn + arrow keys don't adjust actual brightness on an Acer Aspire 5740](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111328/fn-arrow-keys-dont-adjust-actual-brightness-on-an-acer-aspire-5740)

I've just bought the new acer aspire s3. I've installed ubuntu 12.04: it works really well but I can't set the brightness level using Fn+left/right. I tried to set it from the setting menu but it doesn't work.
I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: Have a look on http://askubuntu.com/questions/111328/fn-arrow-keys-dont-adjust-actual-brightness-on-an-acer-aspire-5740/135228#135228 or http://askubuntu.com/questions/21523/screen-brightness-not-changing-on-acer-5742-notebook?rq=1 as they are very similar questions

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem with an Acer Aspire 5750G. This is due to it having a certain Intel system, but a fix and test is described at [the Kubuntu wiki](https://wiki.kubuntu.org/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight#Intel).

I don't have access to an Ubuntu system at the moment to write a step-by-step tutorial, but hopefully that article and [this useful tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/a/135228/81348) should at least give you some pointers.